# How to remove Detection score(percentage)?

Tags: object-detection-api

I am trying to detect custom objects using `faster_rcnn_inception_v2` model and I'm using Tensorflow Object-Detection API.

While testing the model it detects object as object name with score, for example `*Person: 99%*`.

How to remove the score

This is my visualization function

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np,
                np.squeeze(boxes),
                np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                np.squeeze(scores),
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                line_thickness=8)
```

I have changed scores to none

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np,
                np.squeeze(boxes),
                np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                None,
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                line_thickness=8)
```

After changing, I got this result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question, you should set the `skip_scores` and `skip_labels` input arguments of the [`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/c9f03bf6a8ae58b9ead119796a6c3cd9bd04d450/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L594) to True.

You are getting redundant boxes because the visualization function is no longer able to set a threshold on prediction scores when you pass None as scores.

Look at the definition of the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`, you'll notice a `min_score_thresh` input argument that is set to 0.5 by default. Detected boxes with scores less than 0.5 are not visualized by default, unless you don't pass `scores` to this function in which case all boxes are visualized.

Comment: Thank you so much @Safoora Yousefi... It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using the code provided from the official [Object Detection Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) notebook, or some variant of it? If so, this part of the code here is the part that's responsible for rendering the bounding boxes:

```
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```

To remove the detection scores from the rendered bounding boxes, you just need to replace `output_dict['detection_scores']` with `scores=None`:

```
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      scores=None, # replace here
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```

You can look at the source code of this function in [`tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py). This is what it says in one of the comments:

> scores: a numpy array of shape [N] or None.  If scores=None, then this function assumes that the boxes to be plotted are groundtruth boxes and plot all boxes as black with no classes or scores.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Horace Lee.. I added my code above. I don't have a similar function like yours... can you help me..

Comment: Your code is essentially the same (it calls the same function, but it's just that the arguments are written slightly differently). You just need to replace `np.squeeze(scores)` with `scores=None`.

Comment: I did that..but I got the syntax error: positional argument follows keyword argumet

Comment: Try just writing `None` instead of `scores=None`

Comment: I changed scores=None as None..But after the change I got overlapping boxes.. I added the result in above @Horace Lee

Comment: At the moment I'm not sure how this can be resolved. I didn't get the same overlapping boxes issue when I ran my own script with the `scores` parameter set to `None`. Can I see your code? I'm guessing that non-max suppression is not working properly for you somehow